# Ansible filter by attribute contains a value

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In Ansible, how do I filter objects by whether the object's attribute contains a value?

For example: I want to return the `private_man` object which has attribute `name="a2"` by filtering `private_man` objects where `addr` contains `"1.2.3.4"`.

Here's the Ansible code:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    network:
      addresses:
        private_ext:
          - name: a1
            addr:
              - 1.2.3.4
        private_man:
          - name: a2
            addr:
              - 10.10.20.30
              - 1.2.3.4
          - name: a3
            addr:
              - 10.90.80.10
```

I tried the following:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.name }}"
  with_items: "{{ network.addresses.private_man | selectattr('addr', 'in', '1.2.3.4') | list }}"
```

I expected this to display `a2` because the a2 object's addr element contains `1.2.3.4`

When I ran this, however, it failed completely, probably because `selectaddr('addr', 'in', '1.2.3.4')` is not valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will this work?

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.name }}"
    with_items: "{{network.addresses.private_man}}"
    when: '"1.2.3.4" in item.addr'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use only Jinja2 tests in `selectattr`:
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#builtin-tests
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tests.html

For your example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.name }}"
  with_items: "{{ network.addresses.private_man | selectattr('addr','issuperset',['1.2.3.4']) | list }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just able to use the following to narrow the results from `ec2_asg_facts` to only those with a given variable value in the `launch_configuration_name`.  The `search` test doesn't seem to be well documented, and it may be an add-on?  I thought I would share in case others wanted to do something similar.  Below `appRole.name` could be something like "employee" or "data".

```
  - name: Narrow my list
    set_fact:
      asgList: "{{ autoScalingGroupNames.results | selectattr('launch_configuration_name', 'search', appRole.name) | list }}"
```